# nginx configuration for ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an app on nginx which works fine when I run things locally via curl but does not seem to like it when i try it from an external computer.

On EC2 console I see three different types of ip addresses:

```
Public IPv4 address, Private IPv4 addresses, Public IPv4 DNS
```

which one should be on the server block? My server block looks like so:

```
server {
    listen xx-xx-xx-xxx:80 default_server;
```

When I use the following on nginx server block, I have the following:

private IP address: app works locally on ec2 (responds correctly to curl requests) but does not respond on external requests (curl)
public IP address: nginx fails with:

```
May 11 08:55:59 ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx nginx[1936]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to xx-xx-xx-xxx:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

Public IPv4 DNS: app works locally (curl responds correctly), but does not work externally

WTF should I be using on the server block. so confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use public IP address and have to make sure that whether 80 port is allowed or not